# When I set captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, maxFps) in the camera2 api , the camera turns on late

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

```
private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                int[] capabilities = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES);
                List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(capabilities).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
                if (!list.contains(CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_CONSTRAINED_HIGH_SPEED_VIDEO)) {
                    continue;
                }

                // choose optimal size
                StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                previewSize = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
                for(Size option : streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)) {
                    int areaCurrent = Math.abs((previewSize.getWidth() * previewSize.getHeight()) - (MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH * MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT));
                    int areaNext = Math.abs((option.getWidth() * option.getHeight()) - (MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH * MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT));

                    if (areaCurrent > areaNext) {
                        previewSize = option;
                    }
                }

                maxFps = streamConfigurationMap.getHighSpeedVideoFpsRanges()[0];
                for (Range<Integer> option : streamConfigurationMap.getHighSpeedVideoFpsRanges()) {
                   int areaCurrent = Math.abs((maxFps.getLower() * maxFps.getUpper()) - (MAX_VIDEO_LOWER_FPS * MAX_VIDEO_UPPER_FPS));
                   int areaNext = Math.abs((option.getLower() * option.getUpper()) - (MAX_VIDEO_LOWER_FPS * MAX_VIDEO_UPPER_FPS));

                   if(areaCurrent > areaNext) {
                       maxFps = option;
                   }
                }

                videoSize = streamConfigurationMap.getHighSpeedVideoSizesFor(maxFps)[0];
                for(Size option : streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class)) {
                    int areaCurrent = Math.abs((videoSize.getWidth() * videoSize.getHeight()) - (MAX_VIDEO_WIDTH * MAX_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
                    int areaNext = Math.abs((option.getWidth() * option.getHeight()) - (MAX_VIDEO_WIDTH * MAX_VIDEO_HEIGHT));

                    if (areaCurrent > areaNext) {
                        videoSize = option;
                    }
                }

                int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    textureView.setAspectRatio(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
                } else {
                    textureView.setAspectRatio(previewSize.getHeight(), previewSize.getWidth());
                }

                this.cameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e("CameraAccessException",e.toString());
        }
    }
```

```
private void startPreview() {
        try {
            if(highSpeedCaptureSession != null) {
                highSpeedCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
                highSpeedCaptureSession.close();
                highSpeedCaptureSession = null;
            }

            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

            CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, maxFps);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, 0);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            camera.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            if(camera == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            try {
                                previewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                                cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, backgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                Log.e("CameraAccessException",e.toString());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Unable to setup camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e("CameraAccessException",e.toString());
        }
    }
```

```
    private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFileName);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(100000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(240);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
        mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(240);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    }
```

When I set captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, maxFps) in the camera2 api and run cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest, the camera turns on in about 5 seconds.

And if you record a video at 240fps, it will be recorded in frames below 240fps, just like 100fps.

The maxFps is 240, and I see that the camera supports 240Fps.
The camera size is 1920*1080. The camera size also supports 240 fps.

What if you want the camera to turn on right away?
Help me!!

Comment: I think you are missing the high speed session concept. for example use "CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession" and not "createCaptureSession". as explained here https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/Camera2SlowMotion/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/slowmo/fragments/CameraFragment.kt   take into consideration -> most Samsung devices do not support more then 30 FPS. you can check by your self on "Samsung developer lab"